# Channel<Task> - Writer Awaits for Task Result before Next Step Logic

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, channel, producer-consumer

I have a Worker class, that handles Job messages.

1. I want it to process the messages Serially, so that I don't need to synchronize (lock) its internal data changes between multi threaded callers.
   For that purpose I use a Channel (multi write, single read).
2. Sometimes the calling user (the Job message writer), would like to wait for the Job to be completed, and to get some output result (let's say a string).
   Because the user wants to continue to do following steps based on the Job result.
   For that purpose I create the channel as `Channel<Task<string>>` (multi write, single read).

```
private Channel<Task<string>> Tasks;

private void Start()
{
    Tasks = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Task<string>>(new UnboundedChannelOptions()
    {
        SingleReader = true,
        SingleWriter = false,
        AllowSynchronousContinuations = false,
    });

    Task.Run(async () => {
        while (true)
            await JobHandle(await Tasks.Reader.ReadAsync());
    });
}

private async Task JobHandle(Task<string> task) { task.Start(); await task; }

public async Task UserCall()
{
    Task job;
    await Tasks.Writer.WriteAsync(job = new Task<string>(JobLengthy));

    if (job.Result == "Ok")
        Console.WriteLine("Success.")
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Failed.")

}

private string JobLengthy() { return "Ok"; }
```

*. This is a small sample for a server handling multiple (1-10) messages per second.

I tried it, and it works as expected, but I don't know if it is a legitimate approach.

1. Do you think it is a legitimate approach ?
2. Maybe you know any other better approach ?

Comment: Can you show also the consumer part of the producer/consumer pair? I can see that the producer launches the `Task`, so what is left for the consumer to do?

Comment: Thank you, I added the full consumer. The main idea is that the Job exposes a Task for the caller, so the caller can async await that Task, and than continue with something else.

Comment: From revision 3 to 4 you changed the `job` from `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)` to `new Task<string>(JobLengthy)`. The first `Task` is hot and the second cold. A cold `Task` will never complete, unless someone [starts it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) or [run it synchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously). So something is missing in your demo.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I added 'task.Start()' in JobHandle method.

Comment: OK, so the responsibility for launching the `Task` has been transferred from the producer to the consumer. What do you want to happen in case the `JobHandle` fails? Currently this will cause the consumer (the loop inside the `Task.Run`) to die silently, causing future calls to `UserCall` to deadlock, because they will be waiting for a `Task` that will never start.

Comment: JobHandle will run the task safely, it will catch any failure, and the failure will be represented in the result (string) as text. JobHandle is just a stub.

Answer (score 0):

There is  simpler solution to your problem, without using a `Channel<T>`. You can enforce the serial processing of the messages by using a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) with capacity `1`:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(1, 1);

public async Task UserCall()
{
    string result;

    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        result = await Task.Run(() => JobLengthy());
    }
    finally { _semaphore.Release(); }

    if (result == "Ok")
        Console.WriteLine("Success.")
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Failed.")
}
```

The `SemaphoreSlim` is not documented to be FIFO, but the [current implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs#L595) (.NET 7) of the [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync) method places pending tasks in a linked-list structure (`m_asyncHead`/`m_asyncTail` fields), with FIFO behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know semaphore has async wait.

Comment: @DanielGordon in case this answer solves your problem, you could consider marking it as the accepted answer.